# The location of source code for torch.mean()

Tags: python, pytorch, documentation

I'm trying to find the source code for torch.mean and am unable to find it in the pytorch github. [It](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.mean) is under math operations but I can't find it at all.

I've looked everywhere and inspected most pages under pytorch/torch and am still unable to find it.

I even did ?? in a jupyter notebook but it just returned a useless docstring

Comment: Hey Elizabeth. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since operations components are written in C++, they are not callable with operations such as ?? or "__file__" or "getsourcefile" type of operations.

The files appear to be here, written in C++:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/operators/mean_op.cc
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/operators/mean_op.h