# Looking for the implementation of the math operations in the pytorch library. (such as torch.add, troch.mm etc.)

Tags: pytorch

I want to have the source code for the math operations of pytorch. I know they are not all in the same file but hopefully someone can help me. I saw that there is an Aten folder on the github of pytorch but for me its quite confusing to go through.

Its my first question here. Sorry for anything annoying.

Comment: Are you searching for the operation on GPU or CPU, for C++ or Python?

Comment: Hey , im lookin for the c++ code for the cpu implementation.

Comment: this might help a little, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786479/8243797